# In MySql whats the difference between != NULL and IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, isnull

I get different results when i run select queries with `!= NULL` OR `IS NOT NULL` .

```
    /** No results returned.*/
        SELECT *
        FROM PORT_INFO
        WHERE PORT_CODE != NULL;

   /** Results are returned.*/
    SELECT *
    FROM PORT_INFO
    WHERE PORT_CODE IS NOT NULL;
```

- In My Table, PORT_CODE column is nullable.
- Column is of type VARCHAR(4) .
- MySql Version 5.5.13 enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

So basically `IS NOT NULL` will actually do what you intend, while `!=` will do nothing useful (since it too will just return `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, there is no value that is equal to NULL, including NULL itself. To get what you expect, use IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Any comparison or operation with `NULL` returns `NULL`, with the exception of `IS NULL`.

A `NULL` boolean is considered to be false.

So, expressions like `<> NULL`, `= NULL`, and so on are always false.

This is ANSI standard behavior.